# CSS Modules styling is blocked by CSP wihout unsafe-inline for style-src directive

Tags: css, reactjs, content-security-policy, css-modules

I have a React app created with CRA and I'm using CSS modules to style the components.

I create CSS files with the `.module.css` prefix. Example: `ComponentName.module.css`

Afterwards I import the CSS file inside the component I want to use it like so:

`import styles from "./css/ComponentName.module.css";`

Finally I apply the styling using the `className` attribute:

```
const welcomeText = (
    <div className={styles["welcome-text"]}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>Welcome</h1>
    </div>
);
```

However, by using CSP and setting the `style-src` directive to `'self'` all the styling is blocked. I have to also add `'unsafe inline'` for it to work.

Is there a way to define the `.module.css` files and their usage with `className` as valid sources for the `style-src` directive?
If not, what other ways of styling React components are there that are also compatible with `style-src 'self'` without needing `'unsafe-inline'`? Would styled components work?

Or would it be safe to use `unsafe-inline` to style components with CSS Modules?

Thank you!

I have tried looking for answers on Google on how to make compatible the usage of CSS modules with CSP but I haven't found any.

EDIT:
The CSP config I want to use is this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self' http://localhost:8090
img-src data: https: http:;
script-src 'self';
font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;
style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com;"/>
```

However, when loading the page, all the CSS is gone and console logs these errors multiple times:

```
 Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“style-src”). styleTagTransform.js:12
 Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“style-src”). insertBySelector.js:36
```

To get rid of the errors and have the applied CSS work, the `unsafe-inline` has to be added:

```
 style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline';"
```

Comment: Adding the error messages you see and the policy you are using would make it easier to answer.

Comment: @Halvor Sakshaug I have added the content policy and the errors logged in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you don't have inline styles in your html code you have javascript files injecting styles inline. Rather have the javascript code modify css selectors and move the css code itself to a css file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "have the javascript code modify css selectors", and all css code is already in their own .css file. I also tried with just creating a button.css file with a `.button {color: red;}` and importing it in the component and using it like so `<button className="button">X</button>` and the CSP still issues the errors and removes the applied styling. How can I style the HTML in my components while being `style-src 'self'` complaint?

Comment: The error massages indicate that it originates in styleTagTransform.js and insertBySelector.js. See if you can click the file name and line number to be able to see the exact location. You likely need to make this code modify className, not style on elements.

Comment: Well those files are not written by me and I don't think I should/can modify them. I think I'm going to leave in  `unsafe-inline` for style-src because a non CSS-in-JS solution for a component based JS library like React is hard or very inconvenient to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: If those are external you have two options: Add the hash and 'unsafe-hashes' if the code inserted is mostly static. Otherwise accept 'unsafe-inline' for style and lock down the rest of your policy, see https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/